# Method on class [com.docu.MemberInfo] was used outside of a Grails application

Tags: grails, redis, spring-session

My environment is Grails 2.5.3 and I want to use redis cache. I have added 
grails plugin spring-session:1.2 in Build.groovy

In resources.xml following is the redis related settings

```
<cache:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="grailsCacheKeyGenerator" class="com.docu.commons.redis.GrailsCacheKeyGenerator"/>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionRedisTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Following is the code (in a component class) that generates error when I call the validation() method of the domain object, the error is - Method on class  [com.docu.MemberInfo]  was used outside of a Grails application.

@Component(memberAction)

Class MemberAction{

```
    public void save(){

            MemberInfo mi = new MemberInfo()
            mi.properties = params
            mi.validate()

    }
```

}

What should I do. Note that if I remove the plugin spring-session:1.2 and the related settings from resource.xml file then my code works well.